# how to add URL hook to html

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am creating a simple HTML document of an HTML table (with python pandas). I would like to add hooks to rows of the table, so I can access them from the browser address bar.

For example:
Link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki#Characteristics
instead of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by looking on a wikipedia page source.

Replace the elements of row_id on the pandas data-frame with the following html code

```
'<span class="mw-headline" id="%s">%s</span>'%(rid, rid)
```

Can be applied with .apply() method, before using `df.to_html()`:

```
df['row_id'] = df.row_id.apply(lambda rid: '<span class="mw-headline" id="%s">%s</span>'%(rid, rid))
```